# error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.24.1_0' Reader: '703.0.31_0') with XCode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, bitcode

I got the error when archive my app.

```
error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.24.1_0' Reader: '703.0.31_0')
```

I'm using XCode 7.3.1
Target 8.0
Enabled Bitcode

I was successed to archive the build last week but I got this issue today.
I don't know where is the bitcode version come from.
Could anyone family with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, I meet this issue before. I install new Xcode 8 beta and everything was solved. :)

Comment: So the issue was, I had a library, compiled with xcode 8 linked with my project and I was on Xcode 7.3.1. I had a privilege to use previous version of library and it resolved. (a dirty hack though)

Comment: Same with me.
I was using buddybuild and had Xcode version 8.2.1 selected. Once I changed that to 8.3.1 the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled bitcode for my pod and my project. It worked.